# SDL Tridion 2009 - Unable to create an Event System Object

Tags: tridion

We are using SDL Tridion 2009.

Some time ago we start to get this error "Unable to create an Event System Object".
We start to get this error sporadic.

It might be something with our Events implementation, but that was functional more than 2 years,  and we start to get this error just a some time ago.

Just in case someone got something similar, and it can help.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you added any additional/scaled out servers recently. You need to make sure your event system is on all servers that fire events (i.e. Publishing servers etc)

Comment: Cristina, can you please check the Event Viewer logs on the CMS servers and see if you can see any more errors or stack traces?

Comment: Hi, I have checked I couldn't see more errors. But I think Cris was right on one of our publisher server the Page events wasn't set on. For that particular publisher I made the test and I got the error. I will try to see if I fix this I will still get the error. I will let anyone now after I do the test.

Answer (score 5):

This error is raised during the initialization of the event. The typical suspects here are errors in the constructor of the Event System, like trying to load a configuration file that doesn't exist (without proper error handling) or calling an operation that the current user is not allowed to do.

Tridion does the following actions when it triggers an event:

1. Check if Event is enabled (MMC SnapIn setting)
2. Create an object of type "TDSEvents.Events"
3. Set the Identity of the current user (using .Identity on the Events object)
4. Invoke the On[ItemName][Event][Phase] method and pass the required parameters.

If any of the first 3 steps cause an error you will get the infamous "Unable to create an Event System Object" error.